# Ruby on Rails Inherited_resources multiple belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, inherited-resources

I have a `comments_controller` that uses `inherited_resources` and deals with this models:`Comment (belongs_to Shop and belongs_to User)`, and `Shop (belongs_to User)`.
**Rails 4.1.1** and Inherited_resources v is 1.5.0.

Routes are:

```
resources :shop do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

However, the below code doesn't work:

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  nested_belongs_to :user, :shop
  actions :create, :destroy

  def create
    @comment = build_resource
    @comment.shop = Shop.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @comment.user = current_user

    create!
  end

  def destroy
    @hotel = Shop.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.user = current_user

    destroy!
  end

 private

   def permitted_params
     params.permit(:comment => [:content])
   end
```

Rspec that test creation/deletion of comments tell me `Couldn't find User without an ID`.

Thanks for any help.

**UPD** One of the failing tests:

```
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:shop) { FactoryGirl.create(:shop, user: user) }

  describe "comment creation" do
    before { visit shop_path(shop) }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a comment" do       
        expect { click_button "Post a comment" }.not_to change(Comment, :count)
      end
    end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to mention which version of Rails you are on. This gem [inherited resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) is pretty old and its author advises not to use it for Rails 3 and above.

Comment: @San I updated. Rails is 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

From your routes, it looks like you want to deal with `Comments` belonging to a `Shop`. In this case, you don't need `nested_belongs_to`, instead change it to `belongs_to :shop` in your controller and that will take care of it. And add another line `belongs_to :user` separately.

So, your controller will look like this:

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :user
  actions :create, :destroy

  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried and the mistake changed! Now it's `undefined method ``users' for #<Shop:0xd0599e0>`..

Comment: Where is the error coming from. Please post the test that you are running and full output. Thanks.

Comment: The test with valid info and destruction test are failing either.